# Unicode characters becomes ??? in Redirect, in play2

Tags: redirect, unicode, playframework-2.0

This happens in latest play2(RC3):

Two actions:

```
object Application extends Controller {
  def test = Action { Redirect(routes.Application.test1("中文") }
  def test1(message: String) = Action { Ok(message) }
}
```

routes:

```
GET  /test              controllers.Application.test
GET  /test1/:title      controllers.Application.test1(title)
```

When I visit `/test`, the response header is:

```
303
Content-Length  0
Location    /test1/??
```

You can see the unicode `中文` becomes `??`.

Is it a bug, or do I miss something?